# Reading in an individual element and its nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

So I have this:

```
<Configuration>
  <Name>VendorCode</Name>
  <Type>Value</Type>
  <UISettings>
  <Control>
  <Name>DataFieldSelector</Name>
    <Type>Value</Type>
  </Control>
  </UISettings>
  <Values>
   <Required>
     <VendorCode />
   </Required>
  <Optional />
 </Values>
</Configuration>
```

and from this, using C# I want a new `XDocument` like this:

```
<Values>
  <Required>
    <VendorCode />
  </Required>
  <Optional />
</Values>
```

I know how to get individual elements and nodes, but not a whole chunk including children level.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var values = doc.Root.Element("Values");
```

Getting the `Root`, then specifying that you want the `Element` "Values" will return everything as you describe.

Here's a [DotNet Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/Vx2asM)